# Is it always possible to make two vectors orthogonal in the following case?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Say we have two vectors, $a$ and $b$, that take a form like this:

$$
a = \begin{pmatrix}
f_a(0) \\ f_a(1) \\ f_a(2) \\ \vdots
\end{pmatrix},
b = \begin{pmatrix}
f_b(0) \\ f_b(1) \\ f_b(2) \\ \vdots
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $f \colon \mathbb{N} \mapsto \{0, 1\}$ for both $a$ and $b$

Let's make a few constraints. First, $a \neq b$. Second, $\exists n$ such that $f_a(n) = f_b(n)$. And lastly, both $f_a(x)$ and $f_b(x)$ equal $1$ the same amount of times.

My question is this:

Imagine we could add a complex phase to each index of both $a$ and $b$. Is there always a way for us to add a complex phase such that the vectors are orthogonal?

A quick example is this:

$$
a = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}, \:
b = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can alter these vectors:

$$
a^\prime = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}, \:
b^\prime = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And these are orthogonal (their inner product is $0$). I believe this will be true when the number of overlaps between $f_a$ and $f_b$ is even. Is it true for odd times too? And if so, is it always true?

Comment: how did you alter? what does "adding a complex phase" mean here?

Comment: @whoisit I mean if we multiply each term in either vector by an $e^{i\theta(x)}$ term. Here, $x$ is the index in the vector. Thus, each index gets multiplied by a complex phase.

Comment: $a[0]=1$ and $b[0]=1$. But, $a'[0] =1$ and $b'[0]=-1$. Are you randomly replacing non-zero entries with a number on the unit circle?

Comment: @whoisit Yes. I am asking if there is a "random" way to alter $a$ and $b$ by multiplying each term by a complex phase. In the case I provided, I multiplied b[0] by $-1$ ($e^{i\pi}$) and a[1] by $-1$.

Comment: I think that it is equivalent to what you're saying "replacing non-zero entries with a number on the unit circle."

Comment: The inner product of $a'$ and $b'$ is $-2$, isn't it?

Comment: @whoisit Oh, thank you for pointing that out. I made a mistake. $a^\prime$[1] should be $1$ not $-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a[m]=0$ or $b[m]=0$ then let both $a'[m]=a[m]$ and $b'[m]=b[m]$.

Suppose the number of $m$ such that $a[m]=b[m]=1$ is k. 
Let's call them $m_1, ..., m_k$

Then, keep $a[m]$s the same.

The inner product now essentially becomes $\sum_{j=1}^{k}b[m_j]$

Replace all $b[m_j]$s with the $k$th roots of unity.

As long as $k>1$, you can thus get the sum to be zero.

Comment: Oh. The roots of unity sum to $0$, which allows this to work for all values of $k$ (greater than $1$ of course). Thanks!