# Is it always possible to multiply vector components by a complex phase to make them orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

This question is a follow up to a previous question of mine: [Is it always possible to make two vectors orthogonal in the following case?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4646763/is-it-always-possible-to-make-two-vectors-orthogonal-in-the-following-case)

Suppose we are given a tuple, $S$, of $N$ vectors, each with $d$ components. In general, $S_i$ looks like:

$$
S_i = \begin{bmatrix} f_i(0) & f_i(1) & f_i(2) & \cdots \end{bmatrix}^T
$$

(It is a column vector, I wrote it as a row vector as it took up too much vertical space)

Where $f_i(x) \colon \mathbb{N} \mapsto \{0, 1\}$.

Let's define the $overlap$ between two elements, $a, b \in S$ to be how many times $f_a(x) = f_b(x) = 1$. Every vector in $S$ is guaranteed to have at least $2$ overlap with every other vector.

If we were allowed to change any nonzero element in any vector an arbitrary number of times to a complex value with magnitude $1$, could we make $S$ an orthogonal set of vectors?

Another way to phrase this equivalently:

> Could we come up with a tuple of diagonal matrices, where each element in each matrix has magnitude $1$, $U$, such that $U_a S_a \perp U_b S_b \: \forall a, b$?

An "easier" version of this is is:

> Is there a tuple of *unitary* matrices, $U$, such that $U_aS_a \perp U_bS_b \: \forall a,b$?

However this easier version is pretty trivial. Let's call $v$ a set of orthogonal vectors. We can just define each successive $U$ to output an element of $v$ (each must be unique) when given their respective $S_i$. This is why I think the harder problem with only the diagonal matrix is more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not always possible to make $S$ an orthogonal set of vectors. Counterexample: consider the case where $N=2$ and $d=2$ and $S_1=[1,0]^T$, $S_2=[1,1]^T$. Every vector has at least $2$ overlap with every other vector, and we can change any nonzero element in any vector to a complex value with magnitude $1$. However, it is not possible to make $S$ an orthogonal set of vectors, because $\langle S_1,S_2\rangle \neq 0$.

The second phrasing is equivalent to the first. If $U_a$ is a diagonal matrix with each element having magnitude $1$, then $U_a S_a$ is just a rephrasing of the arbitrary modification of nonzero elements in $S_a$ to complex values with magnitude $1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question states that the "overlap" (amount of 1s in the same position in the vectors) is at least 2. That is why your counterexample doesn't work: I think that your counterexample doesn't fit the constraints.

Comment: We can use the roots of unity if the overlap is at least $2$.  [See](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4646772/1110952)